# Probability of two events without replacement

Tags: probability

Suppose you pick a number out of a bag that contains the numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and then you pick another number out of the same bag (without replacement).  What is the probability that your two numbers sum to $7$?

I did this....

$P(A+B=7) = \sum_x P(A=x)\times P(B=7-x\mid A=x)
\\P(2)\times P(5) = \frac 1 5\times \frac 1 4=\frac 1{20}
\\P(3)\times P(4) = \frac 1 5\times \frac 1 5 = \frac 1{20}
\\ \vdots
$

etc etc

$\begin{align}
P(A+B=7) & = \frac 1{20}+\frac 1{20}+\frac 1{20}+\frac 1{20} \\ & = \frac 4{20} \\ & = \frac 1 5\end{align}$

Comment: What are your thoughts? Stuck with a wrong answer?

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.  It can make people suspect you merely copied a question without understanding what the question says.  If you say particularly at one point you ran into difficulty trying to answer the question, it will usually be better received.

Comment: Hey guys thanks so much.... I am studying for GMAT and love to see how other people answer questions. I will follow community rules.

Comment: Your final solution looks good with a little tweaking to the format (especially some hard line breaks so separate equations aren't merged into one line).  Search for the on-site lessons on MathJax. Also, don't forget to accept the most helpful answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In how many ways can you pick two different numbers that sum to 7?

$$2+5$$
$$3+4$$
$$4+3$$
$$5+2$$

How many possibilities do you have in total? 
First extraction: $5$
Second extraction: $4$
Total: $5\times4=20$

So $4/20=1/5$.

Comment: $5\times4$ or $5\cdot4$ is standard MathJax or LaTeX usage. $5*4$ is a workaround for occasions when you're limited to the characters on the keyboard.  I changed it accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

If you pick 1, then you can't get 7.

If you pick 2, you must get 5. The chances of this is $\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{20}$

If you pick 3, you must get 4.

etc.

I am writing out a tree diagram.

There are eight ways to get a sum of 7 (2+5 and 5+2 count as two ways here). Each way has a change of 1/20. You can take it from here.

Comment: 8 ways to get a sum of 7?

Comment: yes. think about it.

Comment: 2+5,3+4,4+3,5+2. What other ways are there?

Comment: You're totally right; there are four. I was counting each one twice somehow.